# Zombie.js check dynamic updates

Tags: node.js, zombie.js

I am trying to scrape content from a web page that is continuously changing. I have been able to use PhantomJS to achieve this however wanted a lighter weight solution. The following code gets the correct value the first time it prints to the console. However on following iterations the same value is printed. Any ideas?

```
var Browser = require("zombie");
var assert = require("assert");

// Load the page from localhost
browser = new Browser()
browser.visit("http://www.timeanddate.com/worldclock/usa/los-angeles", function () { 

  setInterval(function(){
    console.log(browser.text('#ct'));
  },10000);
});
```

Note the example above is purely an example. I know this would be the most inefficient way to get the time in Los Angeles.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once you call `browser.visit()`, the `browser` stores the response, but unless you call it multiple times, the response won't change. See it for yourself:

```
browser.visit("http://www.timeanddate.com/worldclock/usa/los-angeles", function () { 
  console.log(browser.html()); // will print the HTML to stdout
});
```

So what you probably want is to call `browser.visit()` more than once, maybe inside `setInterval()` (although there may be more robust solutions out there).

I readapted your code:

```
var Browser = require("zombie");
var assert = require("assert");

var browser = new Browser();

setInterval(function () {
  browser.visit("http://www.timeanddate.com/worldclock/usa/los-angeles", function () {
    console.log(browser.text('#ct'));
  });
}, 10000);
```

Comment: This is what I expected. I was hoping I wouldnt have to make multiple requests. Thanks.